# How to get the complete log for bean shell scripts in jmeter

Tags: logging, jmeter, beanshell

I am using Apache JMeter 3.1 and in my test suite I have a `BeanShell PreProcessor`. When I run the scrip, in the `Log Viewer` I can see there are errors in the bean shell script. But the error message is very limited, how can I get the complete error?

For example, an error I see in the `Log Viewer` is as follows,

``` ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``// Following is a sample for input // "abc.org/def/xyz . . . '' ```

Is there a way I can retrieve the complete error?

Comment: For those using the GUI without a log file, logger.[error/info/etc] logs appear when you click the yellow warning sign in the upper right.

Answer (score 7):

You can enable debug output in at least 2 ways:

- Adding [debug() directive](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) to the beginning of your Beanshell script - debugging output will go to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (JMeter console)
- Putting your code inside the [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

  ```
  try {
      //your code here
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
      log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
      throw ex
  }
  ```

  This way full exception stacktrace will be available in *jmeter.log* file

I would rather recommend switching to [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy is more Java-compliant and provides better performance. See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for details.